# numpy circular mask cut-outs truncated at edges of 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array and I want to mask circular regions around a few specific elements. This is easy for elements not near the edges. But when the disc becomes truncated for positions near the edge of the array the masking operation throws an exception.

What's a good way to mask those edge sources? Periodic padding..? Thanks!

Here's some code:

```
import numpy as np

x_count = 20000
y_count = 20000

a = np.arange(y_count * x_count).reshape(y_count, x_count) # data
master_mask=np.zeros(a.shape).astype(bool)

coords=([10,50],[500,400])
nsrc=len(coords)
mask_radius=100 # 10, 20, etc.

for isrc in range(nsrc):
    xc=coords[isrc][0]; yc=coords[isrc][1]
    x,y = np.ogrid[-mask_radius:mask_radius+1,-mask_radius:mask_radius+1]
    minimask = x*x + y*y <= mask_radius*mask_radius
    box=master_mask[xc-mask_radius:xc+mask_radius+1,yc-mask_radius:yc+mask_radius+1]
    assert(minimask.shape==box.shape), 'This assertion should fail for discs touching the edge'
    master_mask[xc-mask_radius:xc+mask_radius+1,yc-mask_radius:yc+mask_radius+1] += minimask

print master_mask
```

Comment: show us your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible (pedestrian) answer, though I'd hoped there'd be a more numpy-esque way.

```
import numpy as np

x_count = 20000
y_count = 20000

a = np.arange(y_count * x_count).reshape(y_count, x_count) # data
master_mask=np.zeros(a.shape).astype(bool)

coords=([10,50],[500,400])
nsrc=len(coords)
mask_radius=100 # 10, 20, etc.

for isrc in range(nsrc):
    xc=coords[isrc][0]; yc=coords[isrc][1]
    # Truncate the postage-stamp mask here
    xmin=max(xc-mask_radius,0); xmax=min(xc+mask_radius+1,x_count)
    ymin=max(yc-mask_radius,0); ymax=min(yc+mask_radius+1,y_count)
    x,y = np.ogrid[xmin:xmax,ymin:ymax]

    minimask = x*x + y*y <= mask_radius*mask_radius
    box=master_mask[xmin:xmax,ymin:ymax]
    #assert(minimask.shape==box.shape), 'This assertion should fail for discs near the edge'
    master_mask[xmin:xmax,ymin:ymax] += minimask

print master_mask
```

Comment: If you can be sure that mask_radius is the same for all coordinates, you can precompute a circular mask and then slice it for each coordinate near the edge of master_mask.

Comment: By design mask_radius is the same for all coords.

Comment: Compute `minimask` outside the loop starting with `x,y = np.ogrid[-mask_radius:mask_radius+1,-mask_radius:mask_radius+1]`. The result will be an `(mask_radius*2+1,mask_radius*2+1)`-shaped array with dtype `bool`. Whenever `xc` or `yc` is close to the edge of `master_mask`, compute the slices of `minimask` that correspond to the slices of `master_mask` surrounding `xc,yc`. Looking at your code, `xmin:xmax,ymin:ymax` are the slices of master_mask, so the corresponding slices of `minimask` would be (I think) `xmin+mask_radius-xc:xmax+mask_radius-xc,ymin+mask_radius-yc:ymax+mask_radius-yc`.

Comment: Then, it's just `master_mask[bluh] |= minimask[bluh bluh]`